# Is there any way to join two columns with a minus sign and covered by round backets to show confidence intervals in one column

Tags: r, confidence-interval

```
Values = c(2,3,4,5.4,6,1)
upper_limit = c(1.1,2,3,3.2,4,5)
lower_limit = c(3.4 ,2.4,2.2,3.3,3.3,5.2)
df =data.frame(Values,lower_limit,upper_limit)
df
```

I want to create a new 4th column that has both upper limit and lower limit as (L-U) as below

```
           Upper and Lower limit
              (3.4-1.1)
              (2.4-2.0)
              (2.2-3.0)
              (3.3-3.2)
              (3.3-4.0)
              (5.2-5.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use `sprintf`

```
df$lab <- with(df, sprintf('(%.2f-%.2f)', lower_limit, upper_limit))
df$lab
#[1] "(3.40-1.10)" "(2.40-2.00)" "(2.20-3.00)" "(3.30-3.20)" "(3.30-4.00)" "(5.20-5.00)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `paste0`:

```r
df$lab <- with(df, paste0("(", lower_limit, "-", upper_limit, ")"))
df

  Values lower_limit upper_limit       lab
1    2.0         3.4         1.1 (3.4-1.1)
2    3.0         2.4         2.0   (2.4-2)
3    4.0         2.2         3.0   (2.2-3)
4    5.4         3.3         3.2 (3.3-3.2)
5    6.0         3.3         4.0   (3.3-4)
6    1.0         5.2         5.0   (5.2-5)
```

To format the decimals as in your example, use `format` as you convert the values from numeric to character:

```
df$lab <- with(df, paste0("(", 
                          format(lower_limit, digits = 2), "-", 
                          format(upper_limit, digits = 2), 
                          ")"
                          )
               )

df

 Values lower_limit upper_limit       lab
1    2.0         3.4         1.1 (3.4-1.1)
2    3.0         2.4         2.0 (2.4-2.0)
3    4.0         2.2         3.0 (2.2-3.0)
4    5.4         3.3         3.2 (3.3-3.2)
5    6.0         3.3         4.0 (3.3-4.0)
6    1.0         5.2         5.0 (5.2-5.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(lab = paste0("(",format(lower_limit,2), "-", format(upper_limit,2),")"))
  Values lower_limit upper_limit       lab
1    2.0         3.4         1.1 (3.4-1.1)
2    3.0         2.4         2.0 (2.4-2.0)
3    4.0         2.2         3.0 (2.2-3.0)
4    5.4         3.3         3.2 (3.3-3.2)
5    6.0         3.3         4.0 (3.3-4.0)
6    1.0         5.2         5.0 (5.2-5.0)
```

Comment: I guess the the OP would like the `lab` results to be also surrounded by parenthesis.